# How can I get my rows 100% wide?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a few issues aligning some rows.  I am displaying a section which takes up 100% height of the viewport.  So when you view this section on your screen, you will only see this section.

Within this section, I have a title and subtitle.  The title should be displayed near the top of the section, but the subtitle should be displayed vertically in the middle of the section.  So if your screen is 1000px high (which will make this section 1000px in height) then the subtitle should be displayed at around the 500px point.  My section currently looks like the following

```
<section class="block-hero">
  <div class="container container-table">
    <div class="row vertical-top-row">
      <div class="col-md-12 centerText">
        <h1 class="heroTitle">Some Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
      <div class="col-md-12 centerText">
        <h2 id="subTitle">Some<br>Text</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And the CSS is like so

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
.site-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.block-hero {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container-table {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.vertical-top-row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.vertical-center-row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100%;
}

.centerText {
    text-align: center;
}

#subTitle {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck3epwm5/)  One problem I am now having is how I currently have it, my rows are no longer 100% width.  This means that the subtitle is not centered precisly in the middle.  I think I have the vertical align working, but now I need to center the text in the middle.

How could I go about doing this or do I need to make changes to what I currently have?

Thanks

Comment: btw, bootstrap actually already has a `text-center` class that's defined as `.text-center { text-align: center; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with you jsfiddle a bit, the thing that's throwing you off seems to be your use of `display: table` in conjunction with Bootstrap's rows and columns. Bootstrap isn't made to work with tables that way, it's made to replace them, so it's sort of fighting for control with the table.

The main thing is it looks like your rows are ending up next to each other rather than one below the other, and that's because you have `display: table-cell` on your rows without any `display: table-row` elements around them, so the browser seems to be acting like there's a `table-row` element around both of them, thereby forcing them to lie next to each other, since they're now two cells in the same row.

Your best bet, IMO, is to pick one grid method or the other, Bootstrap or table cells. Personally I prefer Bootstrap, but that's your call. If you want to go the table route, remove all the `.row` and `.col-sm-12` classes, set your former `.row` elements to `display: table-row`, and set your former `.col-sm-12` elements to `display: table-cell`.

If you want to go the Bootstrap route (my preference), you have options. You didn't really specify whether you'd have any other content besides these two headings in that section, but if not, an easy way to vertically align your subtitle would be to give its `.row` something like `margin-top: 40%` to push it down a relative distance from the row above it. Play around with the percentage and see what you like. Here's an example based on your original jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ck3epwm5/1/

By the way, if your preferred behavior is really for the section to be 100% of the *viewport* height, you might want to replace `height: 100%` with `height: 100vh`. This is a new(ish) CSS3 length unit that literally means "percent of viewport height" (technically, `1vh` is defined as "1/100th of the height of the viewport"; [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)) and thus is based directly on the viewport itself, whereas `%` values are based on the nearest ancestor with a specified height, which can sometimes cause unexpected behaviors.